# How to take input from a text file into an object and use it in another classes constructor

Tags: c++, object, file-io

Im making a game and everything is been taken in from text files.  Weapons,rooms,players etc... but my question is how would i take in a single weapon from a text file of weapons:

```
ID: 1.
Weapon Name: Katana.
Damage: 20.
Weight: 6.

ID: 2.
Weapon Name: Longsword.
Damage: 17.
Weight: 9.

ID: 3.
Weapon Name: WarAxe.
Damage: 22.
Weight: 20.

ID: 4.
Weapon Name: Staff.
Damage: 9.
Weight: 6.
```

and add it into a player classes constructor.
This is the code i have so far:

```
void Weapons :: getWeapon()
{
    string fileName = "Weapons\\Weapons.txt";
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string garbage;
    int id;
    string weapon;
    int damage;
    int weight;
    while(infile>>garbage,infile>>id,infile>>garbage,
          infile>>garbage,infile>>garbage,infile>>weapon,
          infile>>garbage,infile>>damage,infile>>garbage,
          infile>>garbage,infile>>weight,infile>>garbage)
    {
        /*infile>>garbage;
        infile>>id;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>weapon;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>damage;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>garbage;
        infile>>weight;
        infile>>garbage;*/
        cout << "ID: \t\t\t"<< id << "\n";
        cout << "Weapon Name: \t\t"<< weapon << "\n";
        cout << "Damage: \t\t" << damage <<"\n";
        cout << "Weight: \t\t" << weight << "\n";
        Weapons w1 (id,weapon,damage,weight);
        weaponsList.Append(w1);//Appends to a LinkedList
    }
}

Player :: Player(string firstName,string secondName,int level,int experience,int strength,Weapons weapons)
{
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->secondName = secondName;
    this->level = level;
    this->experience = experience;
    this->strength = strength;
    this->weapons = weapons;
}

Player :: Player(string firstName,string secondName,int level,int experience,int strength,Weapons weapons)
{
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->secondName = secondName;
    this->level = level;
    this->experience = experience;
    this->strength = strength;
    this->weapons = weapons;
}
```

Like how would i set the players object to a particular weapon loaded in from a text file and then put into a list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the comma operator in your `while` loop condition. It could be written like `while(infile >> garbage >> id >> garbage >> garbage >> garbage >> weapon >> garbage >> damage >> garbage >> garbage >> weight >> garbage)`.

Comment: @johnathon nope im stepping through my code at the moment.  So far i am doing weapon.getWeaponName() which gives me the last weapon which is staff but when i use that getter in the savePlayer() function the getter doesnt return anything:S

Comment: @Becca as you did not post your savePlaer() function, I cannot assist there. But stepping through it in the debugger is a good thing :)

Comment: @johnathon I created a post for this because its not the actaul question in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380080/difference-in-output-when-using-a-getter-c?noredirect=1#comment23475134_16380080

Comment: Would it be reasonable to read the weapons file once during startup and keep it in memory?

Comment: @brianbeuning yes thats exactly what im trying to do :)